# How to create a vector of complex numbers in c++?

Tags: c++, vector, complex-numbers

I have two inputs(real and imaginary parts) for n complex numbers. I can't figure out how to store them together in a vector such that i can perform complex calculations with STL complex functions. This is something I tried but Time Limit gets exceeded.

```
vector<complex<double> > a;
for(i=0;i<d;i++)
{
    int temp;
    cin>>temp;
    real.push_back(temp);
}
for(i=0;i<d;i++)
{
    int temp;
    cin>>temp;
    imag.push_back(temp);
}
for(i=0;i<d;i++)
{
    a.push_back(complex<double>(real[i], imag[i]));
}
```

Comment: Please show us what have you tried, and explain what doesn't work with your solution.

Comment: std::vector<std::complex> is the type you want

Comment: [`std::vector<std::complex<double>>`?](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex)

Comment: It seem the real problem isn't that you don't know what library component to use, but that "Time Limit gets exceeded". Please give a full explanation of what your code is trying to do, and a [mcve] - then we may be able to suggest a more efficient solution.

Comment: there is no obvious reason why this should trigger a time-limit exceeded. My first guess is that the `cin >>` call takes more time then all the rest. I suspect that you exceed the limit somewhere else in code that you dont show here (I doubt that there is a challenge "fill a vector of complex numbers as fast as you can", usually they require you to do also some output ;)

Comment: just another wild guess: if you try to read more input than is provided, then the `cin >> temp;` will block forever (or until you exceed the time limit, whatever happens first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example I used:

```
double real;
double imaginary;
std::vector<std::complex<double> > database;
//...
std::cin >> real;
std::cin >> imaginary;
const std::complex<double> temp(real, imaginary);
database.push_back(temp);
```

In the above example, I read in the real and imaginary components separately.  Next, I create a temporary `complex` object using the real and imaginary components.  Finally, I `push_back` the value to the database.